# SQL Server 2014 connection string with instance name

Tags: sql-server

My working SQL Server 2014 connection string is:

```
Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=myDb;Integrated Security=True;
```

I need to install a new instance of SQL Server 2016 on the same server. Therefore I need to modify the existing connection string and to add the instance name.

I was trying (`MSSQLSERVER` is the instance name):

```
"Data Source=localhost\MSSQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=myDb;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

AND:

```
"Server=localhost/MSSQLSERVER;Database=myDb;User Id=user; Password=password;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

AND more but could not make it work.

The error I am getting is:

> The network name cannot be found

Comment: try: `connectionString="Data Source=localhost\v11.0` or maybe `Server=localhost\MSSQLLocalDB` .. got this from here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx

Comment: What are you connecting from?

Comment: From the same server

Comment: try to set port (1433 - default value) in the connection string, following example works for me:
"Data Source=localhost\MSSQLSERVER,1433;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have SQL Server **2014** as your **default instance** (with no instance name needed to connect to it - that's the `MSSQLSERVER` "instance", but that name **must not** be used in the connection string!), then you must use a **separate**, different instance name for your SQL Server **2016** installation, e.g. `SQL2016`.

In that case, your connection string will need to use `.\SQL2016` or `(local)\SQL2016` or `localhost\SQL2016` as the server/instance name (defined by the `server=` or `data source=` settings in the connection string).

So your connection string for SQL Server 2016 should be something like:

```
Data Source=localhost\SQL2016;Initial Catalog=myDb;Integrated Security=True;
```

You can go to the **SQL Server Configuration Manager** to see what services are defined and thus what instances are present on your machine:

[image]

Look for the **SQL Server** services - the value in parenthesis is the *instance name* (where `MSSQLSERVER` stands for the **default instance** that doesn't need to be specified as such - just the machine name is enough for connecting to the default instance)

Comment: If I understand, After the SQL server 2016 installation I can leave the connection string to the 'SQL server 2014' without the instance name as it the default instance while the connection strings to the Sql 2016 will have to use the new instance name... is it correct ?

Comment: @Eyal: yes - if you want to have SQL Server 2014 and 2016 side-by-side, then leave the 2014 installation as default instance be as it is - and install SQL Server 2016 with a separate specific instance name and use that instance name in your connection string